# Read value from As400 RPG program to string

Tags: c#, rpg

I am calling an as400 Rpg program from C#. I pass it 6 parameters with value and a 7th that is null and to be returned from the program. I do receive a value from the program in the form of a byte. The returned value is supposed to be either 1 or 0 depending on the execution of the program.
[image]

[image]

I have tried using this `string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);`

Which returns this � symbol. I have tried converting to Hex which returns F1.  How can i get the value of that byte in C#? Again i know that the only possible values are 1 or 0.

Update if I use stringConverter.FromBytes(parameters["p7"].Value i always receive a 1.

```
  ProgramParameters parameters = new ProgramParameters();
                parameters.Append("P1", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInout, 3);
                parameters["P1"].Value = stringConverter.ToBytes(uwDecision.Param1.PadRight(paramLength, ' '));
                parameters.Append("P2", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInput, 10);
                parameters["P2"].Value = stringConverter.ToBytes(uwDecision.Param2.PadRight(parmlenth2, ' '));
                parameters.Append("P3", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInput, 10);
                parameters["P3"].Value = stringConverter.ToBytes(uwDecision.Param3.ToUpper().PadRight(parmlenth2, ' '));
                parameters.Append("P4", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInput, 1);
                parameters["P4"].Value = stringConverter.ToBytes(uwDecision.Param4.PadRight(paramlength3, ' '));
                parameters.Append("P5", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInput, 3);
                parameters["P5"].Value = stringConverter.ToBytes(uwDecision.Param5.PadRight(paramLength, ' '));
                parameters.Append("P6", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInput, 3);
                parameters["P6"].Value = stringConverter.ToBytes(uwDecision.Param6.PadRight(paramLength, ' '));
                parameters.Append("P7", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInout, 1);
                program.Call(parameters);


                var read = stringConverter.FromBytes(parameters["P7"].Value);

                isValid = read == "1";
                system.Disconnect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceAll);
```

Comment: You should read the one byte and then convert it to the required data type, which in this case seems to be a bool. I bet you can use something like BitConverter.ToBoolean(<your byte>).

Comment: BitConverter.ToString(read) returns F1. It returns F1 every time.

Comment: How long it read?

Comment: @RossBush the byte array is always the same size 241

Comment: @RossBush  bool str3 = BitConverter.ToBoolean(read,0); always returns true.

Comment: Can you post the byte value of read[0]?

Comment: [0] 241 as in the image is all that i receive.

Comment: You would think the byte value would be 30 or 31. The only thing I recommend is that you re-examine your offset, perhaps you are off by a byte or two.Is there an ascii 30/31 close to your read position?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155777/discussion-between-ross-bush-and-leonardo-trimarchi).

Comment: Doh, AS400 uses EBCDIC hex in which case F1 = 1.

Comment: @LeonardoTrimarchi a bit (a lot) offtopic, which font are you using? It's nice!

Comment: which font? For what? @LppEdd

Comment: The font in the images above.

Comment: @LppEdd thats all from VIsual Studio 2017 using the dark theme. :)

Comment: @LeonardoTrimarchi I suppose it is Consolas then!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the message is using a Extended Binary Coded Decimal Interchange Code. You will need to convert or translate, however, it appears the system is attempting to send 0 and 1, just in it's representation.

```
EBCDIC Hex              EBCDIC Text        ASCII Translation
------------------    --------------     -----------------
       F1                    1                 241 = 0xF1
       F0                    0                 240 = 0xF0
```

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: Check this post out -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858202/how-to-convert-from-ebcdic-to-ascii-in-c-net'