# ISO 8583 library in c#

Tags: c#, iso8583

I am now working in a payment gateway .ISO 8583 messaging system we are using . I am facing some problem that I describle below :
my binary data is :

```
0111101010111010000001000000000100001110111000001100000000000000
```

I need to convert it Hexadecimal value (8 bytes):

```
7A BA 04 01 0E E0 C0 00
```

then I need to Transferred as 16 EBCDIC characters (hexadecimal):

```
F7 C1 C2 C1 F0 F4 F0 F1 F0 C5 C5 F0 C3 F0 F0F0
```

then I need Transferred as 16 ASCII characters (hexadecimal):

```
37 41 42 41 30 34 30 31 30 45 45 30 43 30 30 30
```

my problem is how can I convert this binary data EBCDIC character and ASCII character . If anyone help me its very needed

Comment: Look into the `System.Encoding` class stuff on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4939317/2856789):
You can first convert the byte array to a hexadecimal string, then convert this to the EBCDIC encoding and in the end you can take again the hexadecimal bytecodes of the characters:

```
    var hexdata = new[] { 0x7A, 0xBA, 0x04, 0x01, 0x0E, 0xE0, 0xC0, 0x00 };    
    var asciiString = string.Join("", hexdata.Select(num => num.ToString("X2")));
    var asciiBytes = asciiString.Select(ch => (byte)ch).ToArray(); // It is safe, as we cannot have any unicode characters here

    var ebcdicData = ConvertAsciiToEbcdic(asciiBytes);

    var ebcdicString = string.Join(" ", ebcdicData.Select(ch => ((byte)ch).ToString("X2")));    
    var asciiHexString = string.Join(" ", asciiBytes.Select(ch => ((byte)ch).ToString("X2")));
```