# EBCDIC COMP value to integer

Tags: c#, cobol

How can I convert an EBCDIC encoded file with PIC S9(04) COMP. to an integer value?

This file contains 1234 in the first line and -1234 on the second line.

Binary:

`0101100011010010101100000101000011101111011000001011000001010000`

Example:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert from EBCDIC to ASCII in C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858202/how-to-convert-from-ebcdic-to-ascii-in-c-net).  By the way, as soon as you would have entered _"Ebcdic COMP value to Integer"_ SO would have responded with suggestions thus saving you from having to ask a question. :)

Comment: Im good with just converting EBCDIC to ACII, but its works totally different in COMP, COMP-3 data types.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I convert an EBCDIC encoded file with PIC S9(04) COMP. to an integer value?

Don't do that.

During file conversion, the binary data is converted using an EBCDIC to ASCII table. The `04 D2` (`+1234`) was converted to `1A 4B`. The `04` (EBCDIC SEL) was changed to `1A` (ASCII SUB), because there is no equivalent for the conversion. The `D2` (EBCDIC 'K') was changed to `4B` (ASCII 'K'). There is no way to reverse the conversion, due to the SUB. The same problem exists with the conversion of `-1234`.

Your best bet is to use `PIC +9(04)`, which will be `+1234` or `-1234` both before and after conversion.

---

Test data using `PIC +9(04)` written to file

```
+1234
-1234
+0001
-0001
+0000
```

Test program

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "z:e1.txt";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    String s = sr.ReadLine();
                    short n = Int16.Parse(s);
                    Console.WriteLine(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Displayed result

```
1234
-1234
1
-1
0
```

Comment: Yes - or transfer the file in binary mode so it is unchanged - which allows you to do the decoding correctly (with the additional need to convert the EBCDIC part)

Comment: @Rick Smith So how does COBOL converts this to non comp type? Is there an algorithm how COBOL handles this data type? I have COMP-3, Singed fields figured out, they all are working. Im stuck on this COMP type.

Comment: @LGL - Normally, conversion of data from any `USAGE COMP` type is done with a `MOVE` statement with the receiving field being defined as (or by default) `USAGE DISPLAY`. A utility is used to convert the file from EBCDIC to ASCII. Because `COMP-3` is not EBCDIC encoded character data, it should always be converted to display before an EBCDIC to ASCII conversion; not "figured out."

Answer (score 1):

COBOL data types with *computational* usage (`COMP`, `COMP-n`) are **not** text, so you must not do any character conversion operation with them.

*Computational* types are stored as either binary numbers, floating point numbers, or packed decimal numbers. `COMP` is binary. The length depends on the number of 9s in the `PIC` clause. *Note* that the binary types are storeed in *big-endian* format.

In your case, the `PIC +9(4)` occupies two bytes, each. For example. if you see

```
0x1234
```

as the hexadecimal represetation of a `PIC +9(4) COMP` field in the input data, this is representing the number (0x12 * 0x100) + 0x34, in decimal (18 * 256) + 52 = 4608 + 52 = 4660.

In summary, mixed data (records) containing fields of types `PIC ... USAGE DISPLAY` *and*  `PIC ... USAGE COMP-n` must never be translated, but must be split into indidual fields, and each field must be handled according to its `USAGE` type.