# VB.net Read Cobol File Fields (Pure Binary, EBCDIC, Packed)

Tags: vb.net, cobol, mainframe

I need to read a Cobol file into VB.net.  Here is the description of the data types from the documentation:

```
All Magnetic tape files are recorded in 9-track, 8OOBPI mode with odd parity. They are created IBM equipment disk operating system.  IBM System 360 Standard. 

Binary - Data is coded in pure binary code.

BCD - Data is coded in binary coded decimal format. (Primarily
for files created by the IBM 1401 System).

EBCDIC - Data is coded in extended binary coded decimal interchange code. :(An IBM developed code.)

Packed - Data is coded in packed decimal format. 

File Format:
1-2 Record Count [Numeric] (Binary)
3-4 Filler (Binary)
5-5 Record Type [B or R] (EBCDIC)
6-10 Sales Location Numeric [9 digit number] (Packed)
11-13 Sales Identifier (3 character Alpha) (EBCDIC]
etc
```

So, I know I should read the entire file into a byte array and that's about the limit of what I know to do...
A) I saw another post on EBCDIC conversation using

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(37)
```

but it is for an entire file.  If I run the whole file through it I see intelligible text, but of course the other fields are junk.  I don't know the language to decode a single field properly.
B) I have no idea what to do with PURE Binary format.
C) I don't know how to read Packed, particularly as a single field

I've tried a variety of decoding options for PURE BINARY, but the number I get for the first field is not consistent with the stated length of the rows in the docs.

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858202/how-to-convert-from-ebcdic-to-ascii-in-c-net to be useful, even though it's C# rather than VB.

Comment: Yup that helps.  The Pure Binary one is killing me.

Comment: PACKED is BCD, but with two digits per byte (i.e., 4 bits per digit). I don't recall whether BCD was big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: Do you know how to decode BCD in terms of the system.text.encoding option?

Comment: It's not an encoding; you'll have to process it manually.

Comment: There is a description of PACKED DECIMAL format (also called COMP-3 in COBOL) at http://www.simotime.com/datapk01.htm

Comment: @JeffZeitlin that site is correct but incomplete.  x'A' and x'E' are _valid but not preferred_ positive sign nibbles.  x'B' is a _valid but not preferred_ negative sign nibble.  This is documented in the Decimal Instructions chapter of the z/Architecture Principles of Operation.

Comment: @cschneid - It's likely that a COBOL program with USAGE IS COMP-3 would not use those values for the sign nybble. Good to know just how far out of date I am, though... :)

Comment: Thanks jeff, any ideas on the PURE BINARY?  I can't continue without getting the record count to know where the row stops at.

Comment: Binary would just be a 16-bit [unsigned?] integer (SHORT or USHORT), but watch out for big-endian vs little-endian.

Comment: BIG-ENDIAN!  That was it.  I used this 

bigEndian = BitConverter.ToInt16(Byte2.Reverse.ToArray, 0)
For some reason there are giant records in the middle of the file.  I have no idea what they are, but finding this revealed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Packed decimal format:

For s9(5)V9(4) comp-3, 123.45 is represented in byte format as

```
      00 12 34 50 0c
```

Each digit is represented by 4 bits, there is a 4 bit sign (c) at the end and an assumed decimal after the 3.

Most languages provide a routine for converting byte/bytes into a string i.e. byte x'34' -->> String '34'. So you can:

1. Convert the bytes to a String representation
2. Add the decimal point in
3. Strip off the sign character from the end and add the appropriate sign to the front

There are other ways:

- Create an translation array and do an array lookup. (See https://github.com/bmTas/JRecord/blob/master/Source/JRecord_Project/JRecord_Common/src/main/java/net/sf/JRecord/Types/smallBin/TypePackedDecimal9.java for an example)
- Process it 4 bits at a time

---

### Other fields

- The first field (binary) might be a big endian binary integer or another packed-decimal. There is probably a utility built in the .net to do this.
- Convert the character fields from ebcdic to ascii one field at a time

---

In VBA you did not need to read the whole file in, you could read it record by record. I would presume you can do the same in vb.net

---

### Useful Utilities

These tools might be useful for testing.

- The [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) should be able to display the file. The **Layout Wizard** should be able determine the format of the file. Alternatively use the Cobol copybook below
- The Java program [CobolToCsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/) should be able to convert the file to Csv

  ```
        01  tape-record.
            05 record-count          pic s9(3) comp.
            05 filler                pic x(2).
            05 record-type           pic x.
            05 Sales-Location        pic s9(9) comp-3.
            05 Sales-Identifier      pic x(3).
  ```