# Converting EBCDIC to ASCII in C#

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, ascii, ebcdic

I've been trying to convert a string containing EBCDIC characters to ASCII, this is my code so far:

```
string data = "F2F1F0F2F2F5F4";
Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
Encoding ebcdic = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM037");
byte[] ebcdicData = ebcdic.GetBytes(data);

// Convert to ASCII
byte[] ebcdicDataConverted = Encoding.Convert(ebcdic, ascii, ebcdicData);
string sample = ascii.GetString(ebcdicDataConverted);
```

But I was expecting that the variable `sample` contained this value: *2102254*
Instead, it shows the same value as `data` *F2F1F0F2F2F5F4*

Maybe I'm not understanding how this works, or I'm just burnt out, this [page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/9.1?topic=tables-ebcdic-ascii) contains the conversion table that:

> translates 8-bit EBCDIC characters to 7-bit ASCII

Is the Enconding that I'm using the right one? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that you're having a hard time because you're starting with a `string` rather than a `byte[]`. Do you have a `byte[]` to work with instead? [An existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4939317/1043380) uses that.

Comment: @gunr2171 Hi! I don't have a byte to work with, I receive a string

Comment: [How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted de `string` to `byte` using a `for` like this:

```
byte[] ebcdicData = new byte[data.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < ebcdicData.Length; i++)
    {
        string chunk = data.Substring(i * 2, 2);
        ebcdicData[i] = Convert.ToByte(chunk, 16);
    }
```

This way it worked. Idk why `GetBytes()` does something different, I will take a look at the documentation